# I have file in my directory. i have imported it but still it is saying file not found..(in Xcode)

Tags: objective-c

I have file in my directory. i have imported it but still it is saying file not found..(In Xcode)

Comment: check permissions or UAC

Comment: Hi Rachit please elborate your question.I mean which file? For what purpose?Is it a library file etc.

Comment: actually my co-developer has send his project for me to modify .after downloading it when i ran the xcode file i am getting file not found error.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is showing up in Xcode in red it means Xcode doesn't know where the file is.  Right click on the file in the project window and select "get info".  In the "General" tab there is a button labelled "Choose..." on the right hand side below "Name" and at the same level as "Path".  Press this and you'll get a file chooser dialog so you can tell Xcode where your file is.

If the file does not appear in Xcode at all, right click the project icon at the top of the left hand tree pane and click "Add existing files to project..".